# Gracenote database

Tags: database, music, application, music-player

I use GRIP to convert compact discs to a format that can be copied to an IPOD using AMAROK. By default, GRIP connects to freedb to get disc and track information. I've been told that the Gracenote database has more correct information for the discs I've been converting. Can that one be queried the same way?

Answer (score 2):

No.  The gracenote db is not publicly accessible.  You have talk to http://www.gracenote.com/ directly to aquire a license to query their database.